# Windows freezing with barcode

Tags: windows-7, windows

When my Windows 7 freezes, I usually see a barcode on the screen or the  mouse stops moving or I hear a loud kind of whaaa sound.  I shut if off and unplug then wait a while and try again...sometimes I can go for an hour at that point or one minute before Windows crashes again. HELP

Comment: Does it happen when you are doing anything specific (watching a flash video, or playing a video game, or something else?)?  Has anything changed from the time it did not do that and started to (updates, new software, hardware changes, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a hardware failure.
Go to hardware monitor of windows and check if all components are functioning.
Or Open your chassis and manually check for any burnt parts.

The barcode thing sounds strange. It could be a virus programmed to do so.
If you get an oppertunity, run an antivirus scan.

Answer (score 0):

What you explain as barcode  sounds like you gpu giving up. Waaa sound might be from fan or hdd. Shoot a ctrl+alt+det and watch heat levels. Best open the chassis and locate exact location of sounds.

Comment: If it's the CPU, pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del won't do anything. Heck, it wouldn't even have done anything back in the DOS days.

Comment: ".sometimes I can go for an hour at that point or one minute before Windows crashes" which made me think there a window of stability before crashes which would be good time to watch temps